# How to find the average distance between the locations

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with source, destination and distance between the locations like as below

[image]

i want to calculate average distance between the locations like, for example
if we take A to B
route 1: 21 miles, 
route 2: 28 miles,
route 3: 19 miles
I am expecting results: A to B --> 22.66 miles
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Is there anything special about distances? Or are you just asking how to average numbers?

Comment: Yes, i need the source and distance as well as average distance between the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  LEAST(source, destination) source, 
  GREATEST(source, destination) destination, 
  AVG(distance) distance 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY source, destination
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' source, 'b' destination, 21 distance UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'a', 28 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'b', 19 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 'd', 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 'd', 17 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', 'c', 16.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', 'c', 18 
)
SELECT 
  LEAST(source, destination) source, 
  GREATEST(source, destination) destination, 
  AVG(distance) distance 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY source, destination
```

with result

```
Row source  destination distance     
1   a       b           22.666666666666668   
2   c       d           16.625
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        create TABLE  location_distance
        (
            loc1 VARCHAR ( 50 ),
            loc2 VARCHAR ( 50 ),
            distance numeric
        );
    
    -- #########################---

    INSERT INTO location_distance (loc1, loc2, distance)
    VALUES ('A', 'B', 21),
            ('B', 'A', 28),
            ('A', 'B', 19),
            ('C', 'D', 15),
            ('C', 'D', 17),
            ('D', 'C', 16.5),
            ('D', 'C', 18);
    

-- #########################---


    with cte as (
    select loc1 , loc2, distance from location_distance
    union all
    select loc2, loc1,  distance from location_distance
    )
    
    select loc1 , loc2, avg(distance) from cte
    group by loc1 , loc2
            

loc1    loc2    avg
D        C  16.625
C        D  16.625
B        A  22.66666667
A        B  22.66666667
```

Answer (score 0):

This in MySQL seems to work:

```
SELECT 
    IF(SOURCES < DESTINATION, SOURCES, DESTINATION) AS S,
    IF(SOURCES < DESTINATION, DESTINATION, SOURCES) AS D,
    avg(DISTANCE) AS DISTANCE
FROM distance_between_location
GROUP BY S, D;
```